# are new CPUs still vulnerable to attacks like Spectre and Meltdown?

Tags: vulnerability, cpu, speculative-execution

Are the most modern CPUs still susceptible to attacks like Spectre and Meltdown?

Is it worth enabling the fixes in kernel (which hit performance) ?

Lets say high end laptop CPU such as the AMD Ryzen 7 7840U Processor.
Is it fully immune in HW, or does it still require software mitigation in the kernel?

Comment: Meltdown was a specific bug that I think was fixed. **Spectre will never be fixed.**

Comment: I've rolled back your significant addition to your original question. Please don't extend an already answered question. Ask a new question instead if you want to know more than you've originally asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the most modern CPUs still susceptible to attacks like Spectre and Meltdown?

[Spectre, yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_execution_CPU_vulnerability), Meltdown has been fixed for good.

> Is it worth enabling the fixes in kernel (which hit performance) ?

Normally the Linux kernel enables all the necessary defenses by default, nothing needs to be done:

The same CPU as yours, Linux 6.6.7:

```
$ dmesg
...
Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Enhanced / Automatic IBRS
Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
Spectre V2 : mitigation: Enabling conditional Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier
Spectre V2 : User space: Mitigation: STIBP always-on protection
Speculative Store Bypass: Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on

$ grep -r . /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v2:Mitigation: Enhanced / Automatic IBRS, IBPB: conditional, STIBP: always-on, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS: Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/itlb_multihit:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mmio_stale_data:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/l1tf:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spec_store_bypass:Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/tsx_async_abort:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v1:Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/gather_data_sampling:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/retbleed:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spec_rstack_overflow:Vulnerable
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/srbds:Not affected
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/meltdown:Not affected
```

(Mitigation against Speculative Return Stack Overflow (SRSO) has been disabled manually using `spec_rstack_overflow=off`).

> Lets say high end laptop CPU such as the AMD Ryzen 7 7840U Processor. Is it fully immune in HW, or does it still require software mitigation in the kernel?

There have been a ton of [such vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_execution_CPU_vulnerability).

Some of them have been fixed in hardware, for some mitigations in the kernel (they are enabled by default) **and** in user space software (enabled by default in mainstream Linux distros) are required.

Spectre class vulnerabilities are unlikely to be fixed with the today's out of order architecture of modern CPUs:

- Comprehensive Evaluation of RSB and Spectre Vulnerability on Modern Processors: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.09544.pdf
- NDA: Preventing Speculative Execution Attacks at Their Source [https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~baris/public/nda.pdf](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ebaris/public/nda.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

There are still new attack vectors found which rely on the side effects of speculative execution. Some newly detects attacks are for older or still sold systems - see  [“Downfall” bug affects years of Intel CPUs, can leak encryption keys and more](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2023/08/data-leaking-downfall-bug-affects-six-generations-of-intel-pc-and-server-cpus/). Other attacks affect recent and even not yet released CPU - see [SLAM Attack: New Spectre-based Vulnerability Impacts Intel, AMD, and Arm CPUs](https://thehackernews.com/2023/12/slam-attack-new-spectre-based.html).

> Is it worth enabling the fixes in kernel (which hit performance) ?

This depends on what you are doing with your system. If you are running a Desktop PC and regularly download code from untrusted sources then spectre-like attacks are probably not the most relevant risk to address, i.e. there are far greater risks like ransomware, spyware or other malware. If you instead provide a cloud platform where you need to guarantee proper isolation between tenants even if each can run their own code, then such side-channel attacks are important to address. And if you run a closed system were you are in full control of all code ever running, then the risk of a third party exploiting a side-channel attack does not exist.